# Export CSV file in GEE with random points in polygons as rows

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, csv

I'm working with Sentinel 2 data. Currently we have a polygon set with 1000 polygons. I want to choose 100 random points in the polygon set in Google Earth Engine using:

```
ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(Polygon_set)
```

and generate a csv file as indicated below:

[image]

and use it to plot time curves for band values (using Date column). The band values can be calculated using **ee.Reducer.mean()** or **ee.Reducer.max()**.

Any good ways of making the CSV rows as image number + random points number, and CSV columns as dates and band values?